# Can a Certification Authority self-sign his certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I recently updated the certificate on my site and after a few days and a checked with Security Scorecard, I noticed that the certificate is self-signed.

Is that legal and permitted?

[image]

As you can see, the certificate is released to "DST Root CA" by "DST Root CA".

That configuration is considered as a security error by Security Scorecard.

Comment: What do you mean by "released and signed" by the same CA? I'm convinced you're trying to talk about self-signed root certificates. Root certificates are by definition self-signed and function as trust anchor for the whole CA structure.

Answer (score 4):

#### What is a Root CA?

A Root CA is a certificate authority that is signed by itself. This is how PKI is designed. Your consumer device has a storage, where it stores all trusted root CA's.

Theoretically, you could create your own CA and have it sign itself, then place the certificate of that CA into your device's trusted root CA storage. The device would consider any certificate signed by this CA to be trustworthy. In fact, this is how many companies work internally, by creating certificates for internal servers through an internal root CA.

### Is this legal?!

I don't know of any country that has laws and regulations about self-signing a certificate authority. In fact, I don't know of any laws and regulations regarding PKI in general.

After all, a self-signed CA is just "I am who I claim to be because I say so", and it's up to you whether or not to trust this claim.

### Why does SecurityScorecard consider this a flaw?

Ask them. If they consider it a flaw, they should be able to explain why it is a flaw, and what problems could technically arise.

All I can imagine is that the CA is not part of their bundle of trusted root CAs and therefore they consider it "unsafe" - but that is just pure speculation.